# Bootstrap is acting up from slight height pixel change

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I'm using bootstrap for an easy responsive design. However, I moved computer today and was going to work on my project some more and my design is acting up (See attached figures). I have tested to see if I changed width, would it act up; no it did not. I then played with the height of my browsers to see if it did and yes it did act up and displayed improperly. I am fairly new-ish to bootstrap, but I am not sure what is causing this or could be on something on my computer end. I used Chrome for both viewing. I also tested with Edge and it displayed properly.

Look top-right for view port

This is what it should look like
[image: This is what it should like]

This is what I get when changing resolution
[image: This is what I get when changing resolution]

At request, another part of the code which is loaded via JS.

```
    <body>
    <div id="interfaceNaviation" style="position:relative;top:0;left:0;right:0;background-color:green;">
        <div class="navBar"><span class="navLink"><a href="../">Home</a></span> <span class="navLink"><a href="../PRESENTATION/">Presentation</a></span> <span class="navLink"><a href="../SCHEDULES/">Schedules</a></span> <span class="navLink"><a href="../DISPLAY/">Display</a></span></div>
        <br>
        <div id="loginInfo">
            <button id="signinButton" type="button" class="btn btn-primary btn-fixed-width navbar-btn" style="visibility: visible; display: inline;">
                Sign in <i class="fa fa-white fa-sign-in icon-right"></i>
            </button>
            <a href="javascript:void(0);" id="signoutButton" class="navbar-nav" style="visibility: hidden; display: none;">
                <span>Sign Out</span>
                <i class="fa fa-blue-custom fa-sign-out"></i>
            </a>
            <div style="display:inline;" id="signinText">Authorize requests using OAuth 2.0:</div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div id="pres_interface" class="container-fluid" style="height:90%;">
        <div id="pres_options" class="row" style="height:5%;">
            <div id="add-placeholder" class="col-xs-2"><button id="btn_add-placeholder" class="btn btn-success fa-1.2x">Add Placeholder</button></div>
        </div>
        <!--style="left:0px;width:20%;height:100%;position:relative;"-->
        <div id="pres_editor_panel" class="row" style="height:95%">
            <div class="col-xs-2">
                <div id="editor_display">
                    <div id="placeholderContainer"><span class="header fa-1.2x">Placeholders</span></div>
                    <li><span name="placeholders-change" class="fa-1.2x" data-id="ph1">ph1 <i data-id="void" class="fa fa-trash-o"></i></span></li>
                    <li><span name="placeholders-change" class="fa-1.2x" data-id="ph2">ph2 <i data-id="void" class="fa fa-trash-o"></i></span></li>
                    <li><span name="placeholders-change" class="fa-1.2x" data-id="ph04">ph04 <i data-id="void" class="fa fa-trash-o"></i></span></li>
                    <li><span name="placeholders-change" class="fa-1.2x" data-id="Test">Test <i data-id="void" class="fa fa-trash-o"></i></span></li>
                    <li><span name="placeholders-change" class="fa-1.2x" data-id="Test1">Test1 <i data-id="void" class="fa fa-trash-o"></i></span></li>
                </div>
            </div>
            <!-- style="width:79.9%;height:100%" -->
            <div class="col-xs-10 fa-padless-left">
                <iframe id="fake_view" src="fake_view.html" style="width:100%;height:100%;border:1px solid #081D79;"></iframe>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div id="pres_options-lower" style="background-color:purple;left:0;right:0;text-align:right;bottom:0;">
        <button>Restore</button>&nbsp;
        <button>Save</button>&nbsp;
        <button>Publish</button>
    </div>
    <div id="window_mask" class="mask hidden"></div>
    <div id="popup_display" class="hidden"></div>
    <div id="sub_popup_display" class="hidden"></div>
    <div id="sub_window_mask" class="mask hidden"></div>

</body>
```

This is my body code WITHOUT being edited via JS:

```
<body>
    <div id="interfaceNaviation" style="position:relative;top:0;left:0;right:0;background-color:green;">
        <div class="navBar"><span class="navLink"><a href="../">Home</a></span> <span class="navLink"><a href="../PRESENTATION/">Presentation</a></span> <span class="navLink"><a href="../SCHEDULES/">Schedules</a></span> <span class="navLink"><a href="../DISPLAY/">Display</a></span></div> 
        <br /><div id="loginInfo">
            <button id="signinButton" type="button" class="btn btn-primary btn-fixed-width navbar-btn">
                Sign in <i class="fa fa-white fa-sign-in icon-right"></i>
            </button>
            <a href="javascript:void(0);" id="signoutButton" class="navbar-nav">
                <span>Sign Out</span>
                <i class="fa fa-blue-custom fa-sign-out"></i>
            </a>
            <div style="display:inline;" id="signinText"></div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div id="pres_interface" class="container-fluid" style="height:90%;" >
      <div id="pres_options" class="row" style="height:5%;">
        <div id="add-placeholder" class="col-xs-2"><button id="btn_add-placeholder" class="btn btn-success fa-1.2x">Add Placeholder</button></div>
      </div>
      <!--style="left:0px;width:20%;height:100%;position:relative;"-->
          <div id="pres_editor_panel" class="row" style="height:95%">
            <div class="col-xs-2">
                <div id="editor_display" >
                    &nbsp;
                </div>
            </div>
            <!-- style="width:79.9%;height:100%" -->
            <div class="col-xs-10 fa-padless-left">
                <iframe id="fake_view" src="fake_view.html" style="width:100%;height:100%;border:1px solid #081D79;" ></iframe>
            </div>
          </div>
     </div>
    <div id="pres_options-lower" style="background-color:purple;left:0;right:0;text-align:right;bottom:0;">
        <button>Restore</button>&nbsp;
        <button>Save</button>&nbsp;
        <button>Publish</button>
    </div>
    <div id="window_mask" class="mask hidden"></div>
    <div id="popup_display" class="hidden"></div>
    <div id="sub_popup_display" class="hidden"></div>
    <div id="sub_window_mask" class="mask hidden"></div>
</body>
```

Thanks for any help! I am stumped at this right now.

Comment: You still don't have a Minimal, Complete and Verifiable Example, [here's how](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Not these are not _"my"_ demands. What is being requested is what is asked of every poster. Please use the link above.

Comment: @hungerstar I gave everything that is relevant. Would you like me to put whole Bootstrap CSS file for you to view? My CSS files are not relative to anything structure wise; therefore they're not needed and I am trying to keep it minimal.

Comment: I understand that you don't think the rest of your code is needed but the rest of the community will want to see it. After all, you're the one asking for help. I'm going to check back in a few hours and see how you're doing without a MCVE. [This JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/y0u25e0u/) is what everyone is going to attempt to create from the provided code.